# Zero vector in a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I would like to prove that in a linear transformation, then the only thing that maps to the zero vector in the codomain is the zero vector in the domain. Can I just say that because the function is injective?

I would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is a linear transformation, then $\ker T = \{0\}$ if and only if $T$ is injective.

- If $\ker T$ contains a nonzero vector $v$, then $Tv=T0$ but $v \ne 0$, so $T$ is not injective
- If $T$ is not injective, then there exist $v \ne w$ such that $Tv=Tw$. But then $T(v-w) = 0$ so $v-w$ is a nonzero vector in $\ker T$.